# What is the best way to access an array inside Velocity?

Tags: velocity

I have a Java array such as:

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"123","doc","projectReport.doc"};
```

In my opinion the natural way to access would be:

```
 #set($att_id = $arr[0])
 #set($att_type = $arr[1])
 #set($att_name = $arr[2])
```

But that it is not working. I have come with this workaround. But it a bit too much code for such an easy task.

```
#set($counter = 0)
#foreach($el in $arr)
    #if($counter==0)
        #set($att_id = $el)
    #elseif($counter==1)
        #set($att_type = $el)
    #elseif($counter==2)
         #set($att_name = $el)
    #end
    #set($counter = $counter + 1)
#end
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 27):

You can use use Velocity 1.6: for an array named `$array` one can simply do `$array.get($index)`.

In the upcoming Velocity 1.7, one will be able to do `$array[$index]` (as well as `$list[$index]` and `$map[$key]`).

Answer (score 10):

You could wrap the array in a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) using [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).  The new List object is backed by the original array so it doesn't wastefully allocate a copy.  Even changes made to the new List will propagate back to the array.

Then you can use `$list.get(int index)` to get your objects out in Velocity.

If you need to get just one or two objects from an array, you can also use [`Array.get(Object array, int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get%28java.lang.Object%2C%20int%29)
to get an item from an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"123", "doc", "projectReport.doc"};
```

In my opinion the natural way to access would be:

```
 #set($att_id = $arr[0]) 
 #set($att_type = $arr[1]) 
 #set($att_name = $arr[2])
```

The value for this can be get by using `$array.get("arr", 1)` because there is no direct way to get the value from array like `$att_id = $arr[0]` in velocity.
Hope it works :)

Answer (score 2):

**Velocity 1.6**

```
$myarray.isEmpty()
$myarray.size()
$myarray.get(2)
$myarray.set(1, 'test')
```

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

[Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191844/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-an-array-inside-velocity#192018) is indeed correct, although you might like to know that upcoming Velocity 1.6 has direct support for arrays; see the [Velocity documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#support-for-iterative-objects-for-foreach) for more information.

Comment: It's true.  In 1.6-beta1 and later, you can just call most ArrayList methods on your array objects.  e.g. $array.get(0) $array.set(0, 'foo')

Answer (score 1):

there is an implicit counter $velocityCount which starts with value 1 so you do not have to create your own counter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [ListTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ListTool.html) from the velocity-tools.jar. It has methods to access an array's elements and also get its size.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same question and it got answered on another thread

```
#set ( $Page = $additionalParams.get('Page') )
#set ( $Pages = [] )
#if ( $Page != $null && $Page != "" )
    #foreach($i in $Page.split(";"))
        $Pages.add($i)
    #end
#end
```

[Array indexing in Confluence / Velocity templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035177/array-indexing-in-confluence-velocity-templates/17100999#17100999?newreg=4b7840e98b0a44b3b8112a26bcd3689c)

Comment: Can anyone answer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116553/how-to-append-hash-tables-in-velocity-template