# Array indexing in Confluence / Velocity templates

Tags: arrays, velocity, confluence

Our company has begun using [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview/team-collaboration-software) wiki as a documentation site for our teams, and we are implementing a macro called [PocketQuery](http://www.scandio.de/en/atlassian-en/plugins/pocketquery/pocketquery-documentation/).

This macro pulls SQL data into the site dynamically (we are pulling information like site contacts).

It uses [Velocity Templates](http://velocity.apache.org/) to display it's data, however I am having issues when doing simple array indexing.

The code:

```
#set ( $page = $additionalParams.get('Page') )
#set ( $pages = "" )
#if ( $page != $null && $page != "" )
    #set ( $pages = $page.split(";") )
#else
    #set ( $pages = [] )
#end
```

The `$additionalParams` is a list that has been initialised outside of the template, and contains the parameters being passed into macro, in this case:

> Page=Site Name;Server

The code I am trying to setup is pulling the `Name;Server` value from the `$additionalParams` list, split the value if it is not empty, and then obtain the first value.

I have tried:

```
$pages.get(1)
$pages[1]
```

However no value gets pulled (**I have also tried zero as an index - same result**).

Foreach-ing through this array and printing each entry does work - meaning there **are** values in there.

All I want to be able to do is index into the array - Can't seem to dig up anyway of doing this.

Could this be converted to a list so it can use the `$pages.get` method to index into it?

Extending on that would this allow me to use `$pages.contains` method?

Confluence is using Velocity 1.6.

EDIT:

[The solutions on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191844/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-an-array-inside-velocity) and [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751387/how-to-access-elements-of-array-after-using-string-split-in-velocity) do not work - I am guessing (Wildly) maybe the correct objects are not in the context for the template to use them?

(Would PocketQuery or Confluence be doing this?)

How would I go about using the 'ListTool' ?

Comment: `$page != $null || $page != ""` seems wrong - I think you want to use `&&` there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to access an array inside Velocity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191844/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-an-array-inside-velocity)

Comment: You are correct @PaulBellora , Will fix this up, however your second link I have visited before and none of the solutions work

Comment: This might not be the issue, but you would use `$pages.get(0)` to get the first value, since arrays have zero-based indexes.

Comment: I have tried both already - neither work.

Comment: You might consider asking these kind of question on https://answers.atlassian.com/ using the label "addon-de.scandio.confluence.plugins.pocketquer". We're answering questions regarding PocketQuery very regularly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work with any kind of elegance is as follows:

```
#set ( $Page = $additionalParams.get('Page') )
#set ( $Pages = [] )
#if ( $Page != $null && $Page != "" )
    #foreach($i in $Page.split(";"))
        $Pages.add($i)
    #end
#end
```

This initialises a seperate array, loops through the split values and adds them to the seperate array, which seems to be able to use the methods [provided in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191844/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-an-array-inside-velocity)

I could then proceed to use it thus:

```
$Pages.get(0)//Would return "Site Name"
```

And also

```
$Pages.contains("Site Name")//Would return true
```

Answer (score -2):

m.t.bennet is actually right - I tested and it works!!! I took about a month to find the asnwer and his code sniplet works

```
#set ( $Page = $additionalParams.get('Page') )
#set ( $Pages = [] )
#if ( $Page != $null && $Page != "" )
    #foreach($i in $Page.split(";"))
        $Pages.add($i)
    #end
#end
```